# Windows 10 Deactivates on every boot

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

My Windows 10 Home install recently deactivated itself and has a "DNS server could not be reached error." Tried finding a Microsoft Key Service or renentering my key but with no success. Eventually I ended up buying another key but on restart I have the exact same problem. My Windows keeps deactivating, any ideas?

[image: ipconfig /all 1]
[image: ipconfig /all 2]

Comment: Is your internet working? Please [edit] your question and add the output from running `ipconfig /all` from a `cmd` shell.

Comment: The internet is working fine, won't adding all of ipconfig /all release personal information about my machine? Is there something specific you are looking for

Comment: No personal information is in there. There is clearly a problem with your DNS though. `ipconfig` is the first step in figuring out what is wrong.

Comment: Try changing your DNS. Options are `8.8.8.8` (google-public-dns-a.google.com)
`208.67.222.222` (resolver1.opendns.com)
`208.67.220.220` (resolver2.opendns.com)

Comment: Tried both, keep getting error 0x8007232B, tried slmgr -ipk xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx and it worked. Now to see if it stays that way after reboots before adding it as an answer. Thank you though.